# Change Main Activity location

Tags: android

I have removed the `MainActivity` class, because I started organizing my project into folders (packages) and now my application does not work anymore. How do I tell Android Studio that my new main class is in the Activity folder?

Comment: have a look at the manifest https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you had MainActivity in the manifest, put `.activity.NewActivity` for the name

The leading dot means to put the application package, then you follow that with your other packages